# Kotlin - Return Type For Generic Inheritance

Tags: kotlin, generics, inheritance, gson

I have a generic parent class:

```
 open class Parent<T>{/*...*/}
```

and I have some derived classes that implement a specific instance of the generic parent:

```
class Derived1 : Parent<Foo1> {/*...*/}
class Derived2 : Parent<Foo2> {/*...*/}
```

where Foo1 and Foo2 are some classes defined elsewhere

I now need to create a function that returns a different derived class based on some input parameter:

```
fun getDerived(derived: SomeEnumType): Parent{
    //return the correct derived class
}
```

Of course the line above won't compile because Parent requires a generic parameter. The Derived classes are not of the same type, so I wouldn't expect to be able to handle this polymorphically. How can I achieve this? I am familiar with kotlin.Any but this seems like cheating.

If it helps, I am using this pattern to parse json in the correct child class with the gson library (by overriding the deserializer)

Comment: There's not really a way to do what you're trying to do. If you don't know what the parent type is at the place where you call this function (and presumably you don't because it's just contained in some enum that could have any value), then the compiler can't know either. You will only be able to safely return `Parent<*>`, which will likely be mostly useless to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get away with `Parent<*>` but if there is a relationship between `Foo1` and `Foo2` (e.g extending a common interface, `Buzz`) then you could use something like `Parent<out Buzz>`.

IIRC, `<*>` is like Java's wildcard `<?>`. Not bounding the response type will mean you'll need some type guards at the call site of your function `getDerived` to make the response inspectable.

Comment: unfortunately there is no real relationship between the Foos (unless I force one for this purpose, which seems like a bad idea). Parent<*> is a bit more constraining than kotlin.Any so perhaps this is a better idea

Comment: Yep, Parent<*> is quite acceptable. Feel free to accept my answer if it answered your question.